# Use Google API to embed private google calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I've authenticated an account for a webapp and am able to add/manage events for my google calendar, but I cannot figure out how to view the user's private calendar without that calendar being set to public.

It's odd that I can have complete management access but no method to render the private calendar.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: can you show us your code?  if you have authenticated the user you should have access to all of there calendars.

Comment: I have access to all of their calendar IDs via https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get but the returned data does not tell me how to embed a calendar that does not require the user to be logged in to see.

Comment: Displaying it graphically is your job.  All the api does is return you the data.

Comment: You can only see private events when correctly authenticated. If you want to be displaying this data, you will need to use the auth token of someone who has access to this private calendar. It's not very clear to me why you don't want it public if you will be showing the details from the calendar anyways.

Comment: Aye if the feature does not exist then it is my job I expect. @luc In my app I am authenticated and the page I am on is a private one. Still I cannot find a way to display the calendar using Google's embed method in a way that does not require the user to additionally be logged into Google via browser.

Comment: I see, so you are trying to use the embedded calendar. Your observations seem to be correct then. You need to be authenticated to see the private calendar. If you want other people who are not correctly authenticated to see it, you need to make the calendar public.